# VB.Net Run.exe with Form button

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm pretty new to VB so I need a bit of help with some coding.

I made a program that should download a certain file to what ever directory the user wants, but now i want my program to run that certain file but i don't know how to do it since the user used his/her own directory.

Like i want the program to run that certain file no matter where its saved, how do i do that?

I do know this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\")
```

but this doesnt really work since i have to put in a directory before i use the program.

Comment: First you have to show how you download the file and how the user gets to choose the location.

Comment: Store the directory the user picked when they downloaded the file. Then use that when using `System.Diagnostics`. FWIW, though, that would be a security monstrosity.

Comment: I guess the downloader is like this                                                                                                       httpclient = New WebClient
 Dim download As String = TextBox11.Text
  Dim save As String = TextBox7.Text
  httpclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(download), save)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the path of the `SFD` by using `filename`.

```
Dim Path as String
Path = SaveFileDialog.FileName
```

Then run the file.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path)
```

Comment: I'm so lost without any kind of tutorial, where do i put this and how do i let i know which file to open?

Answer (score 0):

Found another way of doing it,
I just used:

```
    file.open(textbox1.text)
```

And made it take the text forom the the other textbox the user browsed the file to